# EF adds unwanted fields in many-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have the following entity classes/models.

```
 public class AppUser : IdentityUser<int, AppUserLogin, AppUserRole, AppUserClaim>, IUser<int>
    {
    // has inherited property : public int Id
        public virtual ICollection<TenantAdmin> TenantAdmins { get; set; }
        ...
    }

       public class Tenant 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TenantAdmin> TenantAdmins { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

I have a class that ties them up

```
   public class TenantAdmin
    {
        public int AppUserId { get; set; }
        public virtual AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
        public int TenantId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    }
```

And the following in my DBContext class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();

    modelBuilder.Entity<TenantAdmin>().HasKey(x => new { x.TenantId, x.AppUserId }); 
    ...
}
```

The many-to-many relationships works fine, the DB has the fields, keys / fkeys I expect.
When I delete an appuser I got errors (which was to be expected) that I should configure cascadedelete on the link.

I tried different combination of extra code in my OnModdeling, but so far they all have the annoying result that a second AppUserID and TenantId get added to the TenantAdmin table. Even when I remove the double-key definition and add an Id property to the TenantAdmin class.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Tenant>().HasMany(x => x.TenantAdmins).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
modelBuilder.Entity<AppUser>().HasMany(x => x.TenantAdmins).WithOptional().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

What do I want to accomplish ?
Be able to freely create an AppUser, Tenant without any TenantAdmin. Create a TenantAdmin only if the according AppUser and Tenant exist. When Deleting an AppUser, all associated TenantAdmins get deleted (same when deleting a Tenant). What is the 'best practice to do this ?

Any link to a good en complete explanation of the .WithOptional .Required ..... with samples would be appreciated. Google did not brought me what I was looking for so far.

Comment: A couple of observations.  What are the data types of second AppUserID and TenantID fields.  Are they int? (Nullable<int>)?  Second, shouldn't the TenantAdmin side of both relationships be marked as Required and not Optional since the data types for the corresponding foreign key fields are non-nullable?

Comment: DataTypes are int. By explicitly defining the TenantId and AppUserId as foreignkey (by decorating the class or by fluent API) it was solved. Somehow the "convention over configuration" was not able to do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<TenantAdmin>().HasKey(x => new { x.TenantId, x.AppUserId });
```

but what about the foreign keys ? You didnt tell EF you already have the foreign key field.
So it generated one to hold Navigation relationship/s

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<TenantAdmin>.HasRequired(t => t.Tenant)
             .WithMany()
             .HasForeignKey(fk => fk.TenantId) ;
```

repeat for other navigation property that already has a foreign key field.

Comment: Thx. This was actually the solution. I do not get it why 'convention over configuration' did not worked this out in this case.

Comment: You can use annotation or fluent API, to say this field is my Foreign key. My guess why it wasnt done by convention is due to the optional versus required foreign key issue. But that is a question for the EF devs.